# Simple Mailslot program not working?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, writefile, mailslot

Using the client and server examples found here: http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/winsock2programming/winsock2advancedmailslot14.html Compiling them with VS2008, running the server and then "client Myslot" I keep getting "WriteFail failed with error 53." Anyone have any ideas? Links to other Mailslot examples are also welcome, thanks.

Server:

```
    // Server sample
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void)
{

    HANDLE Mailslot;
    char buffer[256];
    DWORD NumberOfBytesRead;

    // Create the mailslot

    if ((Mailslot = CreateMailslot("\\\\.\\Mailslot\\Myslot", 0, MAILSLOT_WAIT_FOREVER, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Failed to create a mailslot %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    } 

    // Read data from the mailslot forever!

    while(ReadFile(Mailslot, buffer, 256, &NumberOfBytesRead, NULL) != 0)
    {
        printf("%.*s\n", NumberOfBytesRead, buffer);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
// Client sample

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE Mailslot;
    DWORD BytesWritten;
    CHAR ServerName[256];

    // Accept a command line argument for the server to send a message to

    if (argc < 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: client <server name>\n");
        return;
    }

    sprintf(ServerName, "\\\\%s\\Mailslot\\Myslot", argv[1]);

    if ((Mailslot = CreateFile(ServerName, GENERIC_WRITE,

        FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFile failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    if (WriteFile(Mailslot, "This is a test", 14, &BytesWritten, NULL) == 0)
    {
        printf("WriteFile failed with error %d\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    printf("Wrote %d bytes\n", BytesWritten);
    CloseHandle(Mailslot);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 53 is ERROR_BAD_NETPATH, "The network path was not found".  Clearly you are using the wrong server name for the mailslot.  Use `\\.\mailslot\blah` if the server runs on the same machine as your client.  And don't forget to escape the backslash in a string: `"\\\\.\\mailslot\\blah"`.

Comment: Where did you find the explanation of the error? Using \\.\mailslot\myslot gives me 161 now.

Comment: Any combination of quotes/backslashes still returns the 161 error.

Comment: Ah, new error code.  161=ERROR_BAD_PATHNAME.  I cannot see what you're doing from here.

Comment: opening up 2 command prompts, running server from one and then client \\.\Mailslot\myslot in the other, thus producing the error

Comment: Trivially explained by not escaping the backslashes correctly.  This isn't going to go anywhere until you post your code or figure it out by yourself.

Comment: client \\\\.\\Mailslot\\Myslot produces the same error. I said I was using the examples in the link. :) Thats the code.

Comment: I still cannot see the server name from your snippet, you are using a command line argument.  What is argv[1]?

Comment: I have no idea, this is the code on the website that I copied exactly into 2 .cpp files, compiled and then ran.

Comment: @Shawn: as written, you have to give the server name as a command line argument.  Like "client ." note the dot.  It is easier to test this by not using argv and hard-coding the server name.

Answer (score 1):

I copied the code exactly as posted into two files, compiled them with VS2008 and they ran perfectly.  If your client program is compiled as client.exe, then type the following command:

```
client .
```

or

```
client <computername>
```

where computer name is the PC's name without the domain.  You can call the API [GetComputerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724295.aspx) to retrieve the name.